# my function runs faster than the interval set

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have this code, which is supposed to send a message and add to a variable every 10 minutes

```
function btcb() {
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#FF9900')
          .setTitle("Bitcoin block #"+bx.blocks.btc+" was mined")
          .setAuthor('Block mined', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/710590499991322714.png?v=1')
          client.channels.cache.get(`710907679186354358`).send(embed)
          bx.blocks.btc = bx.blocks.btc+1
        }
    setInterval(btcb,600000)
```

But it actually does it every 2-3 minutes instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found long intervals dont work well. Possibly browser restriction on max time?

Comment: This is in Discord. The first time it runs at the set time but every time after it goes faster

Comment: Youre better off setting the interval to 1 second and counting 600 seconds then resseting seconds back to 0

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre better off setting the interval to 1 second and counting 600 seconds before resseting:

```
let sec = 0;

function btcb() {

if(sec++<600) return;
sec = 0;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#FF9900')
  .setTitle("Bitcoin block #"+bx.blocks.btc+" was mined")
  .setAuthor('Block mined', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/710590499991322714.png?v=1')
  client.channels.cache.get(`710907679186354358`).send(embed)
  bx.blocks.btc = bx.blocks.btc+1
}

setInterval(btcb,1000)
```